# Is it possible to generate a NuGet package with the same version as the assembly?

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package

I would like to automatize the release of NuGet packages for a private repository.

For the version it would be great to be able to use the same version as the one generated by VisualStudio, with

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

For now, the only way I found is :

```
(Get-ChildItem -Filter .\bin\Release\MyPackage.dll | Select-Object -ExpandProperty VersionInfo).ProductVersion | ForEach-Object { nuget pack -properties configuration=Release -version $_}
```

Do you have any better solution?